# script for monitoring ERRORs in log CloudWatch on python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm not strong in programming, the task has arrived. You need to write a lambda function to once a day, retrieve logs in 24 hours, sort logs with an error note, and send them to email or slack.

SNS topic I created, with sending to email, but I do not understand how you can use the lamb function to extract and sort logs

https://github.com/EvanErickson/aws-lambda-parse-cloudwatch-logs-send-email/blob/main/index.py

I found an example on the Internet, but I can not understand how it works and where to enter the name of the group log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.